# Failing at inserting company logo in doc header section

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to insert the logo of my company in the top left of a google doc. I'm trying to get the logo from an URL address. The error I get is a TypeError, it tells me "null is not a function, it is object". Thanks in advance.

```
function createMeetingNotesNextTimePeriod() {

 var doc = DocumentApp.create("name of document");
 var header = doc.getHeader();
 var newImage = UrlFetchApp.fetch("URLofLogo").getBlob();
 var image = header().appendImage(newImage);
 image.setHeight(100);
 image.setWidth(100);

}  // functionCreateMeetingNotesNextTimePeriod
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two things that will cause errors, change them both and you should have it.

**First:**

You haven't created a header yet, you are just trying to get one. Change `doc.getHeader()` to `doc.addHeader()`. Now, this would only be with this situation where you don't already have a header, if you had a header then you would use the `getHeader()`.

**Second**

`header` is a var not a function. You need to get rid of the parentheses after  `header`. Like this `var image = header.appendImage(newImage)`

**Suggestion:**

Add content type to the urlFetch. Like this.

```
var newImage = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob().getAs('image/png')
```

You can find a list of acceptable content types [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getAs(String))

I don't think it would cause an error without it, but I think it's better to add it.

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much. Also, your suggestion was very useful.